# Crystal Report formula error when accessed from VB.NET 2015CE

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report I designed using a Function in my PostgreSQL database.  The report's data source is the following SQL command (redacted):

`SELECT * FROM [SCHEMANAME].[FUNCTIONNAME]({?[PARAMETERNAME]})`

When I go to check out the preview of the report in the Crystal Reports application (CR XI), it prompts me for the parameter value and then displays normally.  Sometimes, for some reason, it prompts for the user credentials again as well, which was causing a different problem, but I believe I've resolved that issue from my application by setting the credentials programmatically.

However, when I try to print/export/view this exact same report through my VB.NET application, I'm getting the following exception:

```
ErrorID: InvalidFormula <6656>
Source: CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion
Message: Error in formula  <DisplayAmountDue>.
         'Dim NetBalance As Currency
         '
         A number, currency amount, boolean, date, time, date-time, or string is expected here.
```

I've attempted to manipulate the formula in a couple of different ways to get rid of this exception, but no matter what I do it seems this same formula is what fails.  The query in the PostgreSQL Function returns summary values from a View that pulls data from a variety of tables in different schemas.  The exact same Views from which the Function pulls its data are used in other Crystal Reports (also designed using SQL commands with parameters) from the same VB.NET application without any error.  The Function uses `COALESCE` commands to prevent NULL values from ending up in the result set, and I've verified the query results by executing the Function in pgAdmin III.

Here is the redacted code that is supposed to produce the report for reference:

```
Friend Sub PrintSummaryTotals(ByVal ReportMonth As Integer)
    Dim ReportFileName As String = String.Empty
    Dim SummaryTotalReport As New ReportDocument
    'Dim ReportViewer As New frmReport

    ReportFileName = REPORT_FILE_PATH & "Summary Total Report.rpt"

    Try
        SummaryTotalReport.Load(ReportFileName)
        SummaryTotalReport.Refresh()
        SetReportLoginCredentials(SummaryTotalReport)
        SummaryTotalReport.VerifyDatabase()

        If Not SetReportParameter(SummaryTotalReport, [PARAMETERNAME], ReportMonth) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'This was used in an attempt to display the report instead of
        'sending it directly to the printer (below) to try to catch
        'the exception a different way.
        'With ReportViewer
        '    .rptViewer.ReportSource = Nothing
        '    .rptViewer.ReportSource = SummaryTotalReport
        '    .WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        '    .rptViewer.RefreshReport()
        '    ' Set zoom level: 1 = Page Width, 2 = Whole Page, 25-100 = zoom %
        '    .rptViewer.Zoom(1)
        '    .rptViewer.Show()
        '    .ShowDialog()
        'End With

        Dim SelectPrinter As New PrintDialog
        Dim PrinterSelected As DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel

        With SelectPrinter
            .Document = DocumentToPrint
            .AllowPrintToFile = False
            .AllowSelection = False
            .AllowCurrentPage = False
            .AllowSomePages = False
            .PrintToFile = False
            .UseEXDialog = True
        End With

        PrinterSelected = SelectPrinter.ShowDialog()

        If PrinterSelected = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim Copies As Integer = DocumentToPrint.PrinterSettings.Copies
            Dim PrinterName As String = DocumentToPrint.PrinterSettings.PrinterName
            Dim LastPageNumber As Integer = 1

            LastPageNumber = SummaryTotalReport.FormatEngine.GetLastPageNumber(New ReportPageRequestContext)
            SummaryTotalReport.PrintOptions.PrinterName = PrinterName
            SummaryTotalReport.PrintOptions.PrinterDuplex = CType(DocumentToPrint.PrinterSettings.Duplex, PrinterDuplex)
            SummaryTotalReport.PrintToPrinter(Copies, True, 1, LastPageNumber)
        End If

        SelectPrinter.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

**[EDIT]** Here is the `SetReportParameter()` method as requested, although, as clarified below, the Crystal Reports formula does not even reference this parameter.  The formula is only referencing values from the query's result set:

```
Private Function SetReportParameter(ByRef CurrentReport As ReportDocument, ByVal CurrentParameterName As String, ByVal CurrentParameterValue As Object) As Boolean
    Dim Success As Boolean = False
    Dim ReportParameterDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions = Nothing
    Dim ReportParameterDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition = Nothing
    Dim ReportParameterValues As ParameterValues = Nothing
    Dim ReportParameterDiscreteValue As ParameterDiscreteValue = Nothing

    Try
        ReportParameterDefinitions = CurrentReport.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
        ReportParameterDefinition = ReportParameterDefinitions.Item(CurrentParameterName)
        ReportParameterValues = ReportParameterDefinition.CurrentValues
        ReportParameterDiscreteValue = New ParameterDiscreteValue
        ReportParameterDiscreteValue.Value = CurrentParameterValue
        ReportParameterValues.Add(ReportParameterDiscreteValue)
        ReportParameterDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(ReportParameterValues)
        ReportParameterDefinition.ApplyDefaultValues(ReportParameterValues)
        Success = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error setting the report parameters." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf &
                        "The report cannot be printed at this time." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf &
                        ex.Message, "CRYSTAL REPORTING ERROR",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Finally
        If Not ReportParameterDefinitions Is Nothing Then
            ReportParameterDefinitions.Dispose()
        End If

        If Not ReportParameterDefinition Is Nothing Then
            ReportParameterDefinition.Dispose()
        End If

        If Not ReportParameterValues Is Nothing Then
            ReportParameterValues = Nothing
        End If

        If Not ReportParameterDiscreteValue Is Nothing Then
            ReportParameterDiscreteValue = Nothing
        End If
    End Try

    Return Success
End Function
```

**[/EDIT]**

This is pretty much just a copy and paste of known working code that's producing one of the other Crystal Reports I mentioned above.  There are only two differences I can figure out between the one that works and the one that doesn't (other than the "obvious"):

1) The working one is based on a View, while the one that fails is based on a Function.
2) The failing report (Function) is prompting for server credentials, where the other (View) is not for some reason.

Otherwise, both reports connect to the same PostgreSQL database, both use the same credentials for the connection (I've added code to explicitly set the logon credentials for the Function report in the `SetReportLoginCredentials` method), both use parameter(s) to filter the data correctly, and both work exactly as expected when previewed in Crystal Reports XI.

**[EDIT]** For reference, here is the current iteration of the Crystal Reports formula in use in the report *(Basic Syntax)*:

```
Dim NetBalance As Currency
Dim CommissionRate As Number

If IsNull({Command.NetBalance}) Then
    NetBalance = 0
Else
    NetBalance = {Command.NetBalance}
End If

If IsNull({Command.CommissionRate}) Then
    CommissionRate = 0
Else
    CommissionRate = {Command.CommissionRate}
End If

Formula = RoundUp((NetBalance * CommissionRate), 2)
```

Originally, I had the formula written simply as *(Crystal Syntax)*:

```
RoundUp(({Command.NetBalance} * {Command.CommissionRate}), 2)
```

This worked just fine when I was designing and previewing the report, but I added the complexity in an attempt to force the formula to read the values correctly when the .NET application started generating these exceptions. **[/EDIT]**

Any suggestions at this point would be tremendously appreciated, and if you require additional information to assist, please let me know.  Thanks in advance.

**[UPDATE]** I reviewed the SO question [Error in formula field of crystal reports when no records found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873941/error-in-formula-field-of-crystal-reports-when-no-records-found?rq=1) to see if I could find a solution.  As suggested, I modified the **Report Settings** in my `.rpt` file to ensure that it is converting NULL values to default, just to be sure that wasn't the problem.  As I expected, the change had no impact on either previewing the report in CR (successful), or printing the report through the VB.NET application (fail).

**[UPDATE #2]** I found another SO post ([How to pass parameters to crystal report from vb.net code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322735/how-to-pass-parameters-to-crystal-report-from-vb-net-code)) where I found the following comment from user **@Androidz**

> "...But this will not work using stored procedure parameters."

**Androidz** was using the same basic method I defined in my `SetReportParameter()` method, but it appears that the problem may (as I suspected) have something to do with passing the parameter to a Stored Procedure (PostgreSQL Function) being called by the Crystal Report.  I haven't been able to find anything yet that explains how to successfully pass a parameter for a Stored Procedure as opposed to a View, but I'm still looking.

**[EDIT]** Per request in the comments, here are some redacted sample output from the PostgreSQL stored procedure.

```
 ProductCode | LineOfBusiness | CarrierCode | NetBalance |  NetTax  | CommissionRate
-------------+----------------+-------------+------------+----------+----------------
 FLA         | TRE            | LLM         |    9311.72 |     0.00 |       0.700000
 FLA         | TRE            | GAA         |       0.00 |     0.00 |       0.700000
 FLA         | TRE            | GRM         |    9998.16 |     0.00 |       0.700000
 FLA         | TRE            | LUW         |       0.00 |     0.00 |       0.700000
 HZH         | TRE            | ANP         |       0.00 |     0.00 |       0.700000
 HZH         | TRE            | LLM         |       0.00 |     0.00 |       0.700000
 HZH         | TRE            | GAA         |    4780.00 |   112.68 |       0.700000
 HZH         | TRE            | GRM         |    7297.00 |   437.82 |       0.700000
 LBC         | TRE            | ANP         |       0.00 |     0.00 |       0.700000
 LBC         | TRE            | LLM         |       0.00 |     0.00 |       0.700000
 LBC         | TRE            | GAA         |       0.00 |     0.00 |       0.700000
 LBC         | TRE            | GRM         |       0.00 |     0.00 |       0.700000
(12 rows)
```

This is basically what the data looks like.  There are a couple of other fields that are pulled by the query that I've excluded from the sample for the sake of simplicity. **[/EDIT]**

Comment: The error suggests the formula has an error. Make sure the parameter is the correct type.

Comment: The report parameter in Crystal Reports is a numeric parameter (hence the `Integer` type for the parameter value in VB.NET).  As stated above, I've verified that this exact same report works outside of the application by providing a numeric parameter value when prompted by Crystal Reports during a Preview operation, so I know that the formula is working as expected.  I've also verified that the code that applies the report parameter works via other report printing methods within the same assembly that are doing exactly the same thing.  I'm adding the CR formula code to the original question.

Comment: I can't see your `SetReportParameter()` method. Maybe the error is in there.

Comment: I can add that to the question, but as I've said, that *exact same* `SetReportParameter()` method is being used successfully by another report printing method in the same application.  It's being called in exactly the same way, and being used to pass multiple parameters to the other report.  I'll see about adding that code to the question.

Comment: Maybe it's because your disposing the parameters values in the function. Also, setting a parameter field is a one liner. I think you are overcomplicating this process. `report.SetParameterValue("param", paramValue)`

Comment: Unfortunately, IIRC the method you mentioned (`report.SetParameterValue("param", paramValue)`) doesn't work quite as expected, which is what led me to put together the separate function.  Also, as I stated, this `SetReportParameter()` method works exactly as expected for another report in the same application.  The parameters are correctly passed to the CR engine, then the report is displayed with the appropriate values based on those parameters.  Besides, the CR formula that's generating the exception doesn't reference the parameter.  It's just multiplying two values from a row in the query.

Comment: Well great, enjoy your day.

Comment: I tried using the `report.SetParameterValue("param", paramValue)` method in place of my `SetReportParameter()` function to see if it would make any difference, but unfortunately, I got exactly the same exception this time as before.  I can't remember exactly *why* I built/implemented that function as I did it several years ago, so perhaps it's obsolete at this point.  I just remember that I had been fighting with correctly passing parameter values to a CR report and this is what I came up with after researching the errors.

Comment: @G_Hosa_Phat Sorry if I'm late to the party. I used CR a while ago but I always passed my parameters as `rpt.DataDefinition.FormulaFields.Item(0).Text = value`. Is this any helpful?

Comment: Also, on the error (at top) it says `Dim NetAmount As Currency` but on the edit you've made it says `Dim NetBalance As Currency`.... Is the same thing? Where is the code for NetAmount? Can you output a sample of the query result?

Comment: Make sure the report parameter data type must the same with the data type value. If not then you need to parse or cast either the parameter field or the value.

Comment: @Jaxedin - Yes, the NetBalace and NetAmount references are actually the same thing. It was a typo. The query result is pretty simple. I'll try to post a sample when I'm back in the office. reds - The parameter value is a numeric value (Integer), and the CR parameter is identified as a numeric parameter.